# Redirecting stdout when using Google Test causes errno to be set

Tags: c++, pipe, stdout, googletest

Consider the following code using Google Test.  Note that I have not added any tests at all.

```
// File main.cpp

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

using ::testing::InitGoogleTest;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    InitGoogleTest( &argc, argv );
    std::cerr << "INITIAL ERRNO " << errno << std::endl;
    int result = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    std::cerr << "FINAL ERRNO " << errno << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

I can compile this with:

```
g++ main.cpp -o test -I/path/to/googletest/1.8.0/include/ -lgtest -L/path/to/googletest/1.8.0/lib/
```

(I'm using `g++` version 6.1.0 and `googletest` version 1.8.0.)

Executing `test` gives me

```
% ./test
INITIAL ERRNO 0
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
FINAL ERRNO 0
```

However, piping the results of this execution into `less` (or piping to `view -` or redirecting to a file) gives

```
% ./test |& less
INITIAL ERRNO 0
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
FINAL ERRNO 22
```

(It appears that the critical redirect here is `stdout`.  Redirecting `stderr` alone does not cause a problem.)

On my system, `22` corresponds to `EINVAL`.

What is happening here?  I understand that gtest absorbs `stdout` from the main execution, but it also writes to `stdout`, so there should be an open pipe from the `stdout` of `test` to the `stdin` of `less`.  Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Note: I am writing in C++11, but I occasionally need to use the bare C interface for things that (in C++17 and later) would be handled by `std::filesystem`, which is how I noticed that `errno` is being set.  I have heard that setting `errno` to zero before calling functions that might set it is recommended by some people to prevent these kinds of issues, and I may adopt that practice (depending on the comments I get in response), but I'd still like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: I assume Google Test does some operation on stdout that is allowed when stdout goes to an interactive terminal but not when stdout goes to a file or a pipe. Try running both commands under strace and compare the results. But why do you care?

Comment: @rveerd I just prefer to take the time to understand things that surprise me.  I haven't used `strace` before, so I'll try that.  Thanks!